# Restarting a React Native application while having a Firebase messaging listener open crashes application

Tags: react-native, logout, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase

Restarting a React Native application while having a firebase messaging listener active crashes application

I use react-native-firebase/messaging to listen for changes to one of my APIs like so on my Home screen

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      console.log('got message', remoteMessage);
      //Do something
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

on the menu screen, when a user says log out, I do

```
RNRestart.restart();
```

from 'react-native-restart'

which throws this error (on iOS ONLY, android handles this perfectly and restarts without an issue)

```
Assertion failed: (objectCounter_ == 0 && "JSCRuntime destroyed with a dangling API object"), function ~JSCRuntime, file JSCRuntime.cpp, line 395.
```

Trying to figure out the best way around this issue.  Doing a navigation.reset() before the call as below still does not seem to unmount the listener before trying to restart.

```
const resetAction = CommonActions.reset({
              index: 0,
              routes: [{ name: 'Login' }], // Replace 'Home' with your app's initial screen
            });
navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Here's my nav stack, for context

-App

- Login
- TabNav

  - Home
  - Tab2
  - Tab3
- Menu

Comment: this is an open issue in the ```react-native-restart``` package repo. Adding a setTimeout have fixed the issue for some. [link to issue](https://github.com/avishayil/react-native-restart/issues/239#issuecomment-1512546693)

Comment: setTimeout does not help from my testing, and it doesn't look like its helped other people on that thread either, sadly. Thanks for linking to the known issue though!

Comment: Also, though this is tagged onto react-native-reanimated in that issue, I think for me it is related to react-native-firebase/messaging and not react-native-restart.  I say this because commenting out the messaging() code in the sample above does fix the issue for me, but I need that code so cant simply remove it

Comment: as error is related to JSC, you should try enabling [hermes](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes). That may fix it